# Formatting Date to a correct string not working

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi i am dealing with dates in C#. I am trying to create a string that i can later on write out in the console. I do not want to write out the time of the day in this string only the day/month/year.

I tried to use

```
bool isDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, null, DateTimeStyles.none, out date );
```

This gave me the correct style of the date but somehow when i return it to a string i do not get the same format.

Asset:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Miniproject_2021_09_22
{
    class Asset
    {
        public string assetName { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }

        public double price { get; set; }

        
        public string office { get; set; }

        public string currency { get; set; }

        public DateTime purchaseDate; 

        public Asset(string assetName, string date, double price, string office)
        {
            this.assetName = assetName;
            this.date = date;
            this.price = price;
            this.office = office;
        }

        public virtual string getAssetType()
        {
            return "Asset"; 
        }
        
        public Asset convertPrice()
        {
            if (office.ToLower().Trim() == "sweden")
            {
                currency = "Sek";
                return this;

            } else if (office.ToLower().Trim() == "usa")
            {
                price = price / 8.63;
                currency = "$";
                return this;
            } else if (office.ToLower().Trim() == "portugal")
            {
                price = price / 10.14;
                currency = "£";
                return this;
            }
            else
            {
                currency = "Sek";
                return this;
            }
        }
        public void createDate()
        {
            string pattern = "MM-dd-yy";

            bool isValidDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out purchaseDate);


            while (!isValidDate)
            {
                Console.Write("The date you entered is in wrong format please enter a date that follows this format MM-dd-yy: ");
                isValidDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out purchaseDate);
            }

            date = purchaseDate.Date.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `date = purchaseDate.Date.ToString(pattern);`

Comment: hmm okey gonna see if this works

Comment: Forgot to call createDate() method from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ToShortDateString` like this:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

The problem you are seeing is that `DateTime.Now.Date` gives you a `DateTime` initialized to the current date with `12:00:00 AM` as the time. If you then run `ToString` it still shows both the date and the time.

See the docs for [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-5.0), especially if you want to change the culture that is used to format the string.

Comment: i need to be able to use a custom Date though not the clocktime

Comment: You can replace `DateTime.Now` with your `purchaseDate.Date` variable. They are all of type `DateTime` and have the same methods and properties.

Comment: this one seems to work without now to :D